# How to get global ip for virtualbox guest os

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, virtualbox, hosts, guest

I'm trying to setup ubuntu server in virtualbox.

Host is Windows 7 x64

Guest is Ubuntu 11.10 x64

All I want to do is, to make this server accessible from internet. How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows 7 machine has an external IP on the internet, set the VM guest's network adaptor to "bridging", and assign it the external IP.

If the Windows 7 machine is internal, then you'll need to set up bridging mode, as above, but then give it an internal network address on the same network as the Win7 host. You'll also need to configure your gateway router to pass through traffic from an external IP to the internal network IP that you assigned the guest.

Comment: Wind 7 machine has external ip. http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/1184/20120127225619.png but when I try to bridge it, guest os - ubuntu doesn't detect network at all

Comment: Have you been assigned additional IPs from your ISP?

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman no

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu Then you won't be able to attach your VM directly to the Internet by using a bridge. You'll have to do DNAT (aka port forwarding) from the host OS.